# How to enable mic input only in headphone

Tags: windows-10, audio, microphone, acer-aspire

I am making a project in which I need to give instructions to my program and the program will perform some output as per my instructions.
Everything is working fine as I am able to give commands via mic and my program is working as per it.
But the thing that is making me worry is that when I use my headphone then the output is audible only to me means the audio is not coming out from the laptop speaker.
I want to be able to make the audible output from laptop also.
Any thing that I can do for it??

Comment: Please add an Operating System tag (windows, etc.).

Comment: I added the tag now.